# How can I filter out the value of similar (not same) row names in R

Tags: r, function, filter, subset, logical-operators

I am somewhat new to the R environment.
I have a set of characters "test". If I want to filter out all the corresponding value of the column from a sample data (which is numeric), I can do it by matching the column names.
e.g

```
> test <-c("aa", "bb", "zz")

> head(sample.data)

aa aa-001 aa-099 cc zz

1   5      6      7  2

> temp<-test%in% names(sample.data)
```

This gives me a logical vector which I can use to get the require data

```
>temp

TRUE FALSE FLASE FLASE TRUE

> req.vec <- sample.data[temp]


> req.vec


aa zz


1  2
```

However, is it possible that along with the values of aa, i can also filter out the corresponding values of aa-001 and aa-099 as well? I cannot match all the variants of "aa"  because the data hav 100s of variations for aa, bb zz etc.

Comment: How would you like to change the results from your sample data? Are you saying you'd like to keep every column that starts with "aa"?

Comment: Hi, Yes i want to generate a set of data containing the values of all the column with same initial names. Actually, only the last four characters are changing for different column names. eg. if column names are aa-001 aa-005 bbb-001 bbb-090 acdb-001 acdb-007 etc. , I in interested in values of those containing "aa" and "acdb" etc.

Answer (score 0):

if they colnames are always of the given format, you could do

```
test <-c("aa", "bb", "zz")
cn <- c("aa", "aa-001", "aa-099", "cc", "zz")
sample.data <- c(1,5,6,7,2)
names(sample.data) <- cn
sample.data[substr(cn, 1, 2) %in% test]
##    aa aa-001 aa-099     zz 
##     1      5      6      2
```

Alternatively you'll you could iterate `grep` over `test`

Comment: thanks! I need to modify it a bit though. As per my problem, only last 4 character were changing. 
So, instead of using 
sample.data[substr(cn, 1, 2) %in% test] 
i used  
sample.data[substr(cn, 1, nchar(cn)-4)) %in% test]

Answer (score 0):

This example uses `grep` to match any column names that start with the characters in the `test` vector.

```
test <- c("aa", "bb", "zz")
sample.data <- data.frame(aa=1, "aa-001"=5, "aa-099"=6,cc=7,zz=2)
cols <- apply(sapply(test, function(x) grepl(paste0("^",x),names(sample.data))),1,any)
sample.data[, cols]
```

Since you mention that only the last 4 characters are changing, then it makes sense to remove the last 4 characters

```
sample.data <- data.frame("aa-001"=1, "aa-005"=5, "bbb-001"=6,
    "bbb-090"=7,"acdb-001"=2, "acdb-007"=1)
test <- c("aa","acdb")
nn <- names(sample.data)
cols <- substr(nn,1,nchar(nn)-4) %in% test
sample.data[,cols]
```

Or if you want to remove anything that ends in a "-" and some digits, you can use `gsub`

```
sample.data <- data.frame("aa-001"=1, "aa-005"=5, "bbb-001"=6,
    "bbb-090"=7,"acdb-001"=2, "acdb-007"=1, check.names = FALSE)
test <- c("aa","acdb")
cols <- substr(nn,1,nchar(nn)-4) %in% test
sample.data[,cols]
```

Comment: That is what i did . Just saw your reply after posting my syntax. Thanks a lot for your reply anyway :)